# ReactJS app to add and validate items to a list

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

I wrote a sample app based on the ReactJS tutorial, and I would like some thoughts on how idiomatic this code is. Unfortunately there's no ReactJS integration with Stackoverflow snippets, but I do have [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abitdodgy/xkm8wdaf/6/).

You have a phases box, and inside it we have a list of phases, and a new phase form to add a phase to the list. There's a link to show the form, and another link on the form to hide it. There's also validation on the form.

I'm curious to know how idiomatic this is. Some things to consider:

1. I'm passing a callback to handle hiding the from from the parent to the form, and then to the link component that hides the form. Seems excessive to pass down a callback through descendents.
2. Validation is very complex, but I have a simple case here: text is required. It seems a bit ad hoc to validate this way.

```
var PhasesBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: [],
            showForm: false
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.setState({ data: data });
    },

    handlePhaseSubmit: function(phase) {
        var phases = this.state.data;
        var newPhases = phases.concat([phase]);
        this.setState({ data: newPhases, showForm: false });
    },

    handleShowFormLinkClick: function(arg) {
        this.setState({ showForm: true });
    },

    handleHideFormLinkClick: function(arg) {
        this.setState({ showForm: false });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="phase_box">
                <h1>Phases</h1>
                <PhaseList data={this.state.data} />
                { this.state.showForm ?
                  <PhaseForm onPhaseSubmit={this.handlePhaseSubmit} onHideFormLinkClick={this.handleHideFormLinkClick} /> :
                  <ShowFormLink onShowFormLinkClick={this.handleShowFormLinkClick} /> }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var PhaseList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var phaseNodes = this.props.data.map(function (phase) {
            return (
                <Phase name={ phase.name } />
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul className="phase_list">
                { phaseNodes }
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

var PhaseForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { valid: true };
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var nameInput = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.name);
        var name = nameInput.value.trim();

        if (!name) {
            this.setState({ valid: false });
            return;
        }

        this.props.onPhaseSubmit({ name: name });

        nameInput.value = '';
        return;
    },

    render: function() {
        var nameInputClassName = this.state.valid ? null : 'has_errors';
        return (
            <form className="phase_form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" ref="name" className={nameInputClassName} />
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                <HideFormLink onHideFormLinkClick={this.props.onHideFormLinkClick} />
            </form>
        );
    }
});

var Phase = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li className="phase">
                { this.props.name }
            </li>
        );
    }
});

var ShowFormLink = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onShowFormLinkClick();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>New Phase</a>
        );
    }
});

var HideFormLink = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onHideFormLinkClick();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>Cancel</a>
        );
    }
});

data = [
    { "name": "Phase 1" },
    { "name": "Phase 2" },
    { "name": "Phase 3" }
];

React.render(<PhasesBox data={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Before anyone who is unfamiliar with ReactJS gets really confused as to **why this code works**, it is JSX and not Javascript, which is why OP can put HTML literals inside of his code. JSX does compile **into** JavaScript and is visually similar to JavaScript so I am leaving the JavaScript tag on. @Mohamad grats on being the first person to have a question in the JSX tag.

Comment: @DanPantry Cheers for sorting out the question, and shame there's no reward the latter achievement! [More can be read on JSX](http://facebook.github.io/jsx/)

Comment: Within your `componentDidMount`, should it be `{data: this.props.data}`?

Comment: It's nice that you're handling validation within your PhaseForm. I started doing that too at the start. Have a read up on controlled form fields: http://blog.iansinnott.com/managing-state-and-controlled-form-fields-with-react/ - Including the comments. It's an interesting read about handling forms in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your code pretty good mostly. Some ideas for possible improvements:

- I don't think that `PhaseForm` should include the `HideFormLink` since `PhaseForm` handles the state for that and the form shouldn't need to know that it might be hidden. I would rather move that up to `PhasesBox` (eventually passing it as child down to `PhaseForm` if you need to have this exact DOM tree). With this, there would also be no need to pass the callback down anymore.
- I would inline `ShowFormLink` and `HideFormLink` since both do nearly nothing (and nearly the same). Also, you wouldn't need to pass down the callback anymore. If you like it more, you can create a `Link` component that handles the `preventDefault` on its click handler.
- Same for `Phase` (IMHO)
- `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.name)` is no longer needed, `this.refs.name` already gives you the DOM node (at least in more recent React versions)
- You can initialize the state of `PhaseBox` with the passed down data directly in `getInitialState` instead of using `componentDidMount`:

  ```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: this.props.data || [], // or using `getDefaultProps()` if you prefer that
      showForm: false
    };
   }
  ```

  In addition to being shorter, it also prevents a [re-rendering triggered because of using `setState` in `componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).